# Get a view of upcoming activites for cases

Tags: joomla, civicase, activities

I am using the lastest version of CiviCRM in the latest version of Joomla

I am trying to use CiviCase to manage workflows but I find the interface counter intuitive

I want to see a list of my upcoming activities for all my cases and filter them by today, this week, etc.

The case dashboard shows mycases with upcoming activities and groups all the activities under each case

This is hard to get an overview of your activities for a certain time period

Is there a way to search case activities by scheduled date and show only the activities themselves or is there an extension that shows all your upcoming activities in one widget, stream or calendar

Thanks in advance for helping out a newbie

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [data processor extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor) for creating views/reports in CiviCRM.

You can find documentation on how to install extension [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/#installing-a-new-extension)

There is not much documentation (yet) but there is an example documentation on how to create a search/report: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor/blob/master/docs/how_to_create_search.md

Answer (score 0):

The stock Activity Details Report (Administer - CiviReport - Create New Report) can do this if you adjust the filters tab to include case activities and whatever other criteria you'd like.

Or take a look at the alternate civicase extension: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase. You might prefer how it works. Although I'm not sure how pretty it looks when used with joomla since it was originally aimed at drupal. There's also a slightly different variation of it at https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase